# R: RandomForest : Having 2 columns in output of predict

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

Is it possible to output the data of a prediction model as a data frame against dates. I am getting my response as :

```
       3         4         6        10        11        13        14        21        33 
3.512291  3.336686  3.770743  3.503125  3.410734  3.990457  2.641872  1.933128  4.030045 
 ...
```

The output I want is:

```
date        Per Re Count
2017-01-01  3.512291 
2017-01-02  3.336686
 ...
```

The dates are to be against the dates in the predict date column.

The test set is as follows

```
date        Per Re Count
2017-01-01  3.512291 
2017-01-02  3.336686
2017-01-03  3.437686
 ...
```

Comment: You can create a `data.frame`, i.e. `res <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01", length.out = length(out), by = "1 day"), PerReCount = out)`

Comment: This would give me all the dates in an increment basis, and not specific dates present in test set. Now, as a workaround, I used cbind to connect the predicted values to the given days, and its quite simple to achieve it. But I wonder if there is a way to predict output with two columns where one is the predicted value, and the other not.